# WPF ListView Sorting issue with Cell Templated TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

There is a problem with WPF Listview.
This listview is bound to a DataTable from DB. There is no MVVM here. Everthing is in codebehind.

In this listview, the 3rd column has celltemplate. And this column is bound to tax percentage column in the DataTable.
This tax percentage column is of type varchar [This is based on some other business logic hence cannot change the datatype].

```
 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox Name="txt1" Text="{Binding taxpercent, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
               PreviewTextInput="txt1_PreviewTextInput" Width="105">
               <TextBox.BorderBrush>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource textComparer}">
                         <Binding Path="taxpercent" Mode="TwoWay" />
                         <Binding Path="taxpercent_val" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
               </TextBox.BorderBrush>
      </TextBox>                                        
   </DataTemplate>
```

When the listview is loaded, it populates the data from DB.
Let's say 4 rows of data in the listview. Below is shown the Tax column.

```
Tax Percentage
--------------
2
1
4
3
```

After this, i edited the tax percentage and clicked on the GridViewHeaderColumn to sort it.
It sorts correctly. Now the sorting order is desending. Below is the code for sorting.

```
    ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvTax.ItemsSource);
        if (dataView != null)
        {              
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("taxpercent", direction);
            dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
            dataView.Refresh();               
        }
```

After the sorting for the first time, when i edited or changed a value in the tax percentage text box,
soon after the typing the first digit, it automatically sorts again !!! means the edited row goes down or up
depends on the last sorted direction !!!

The above event handler "txt1_PreviewTextInput" is just to make it numeric text box.
I commented the above handler and tried. But no use.
I commented the multibinding in the XAML, but no use.

What could be the problem ???

Any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

Change your UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus in your TextBox binding, Currently you are triggering property change as soon as User starts typing, After triggering it on LostFocus your grid will be sorted as soon as it loses focus.

```
<TextBox Name="txt1" Text="{Binding taxpercent, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
```

And if you need to sort it only by clicking the header change your Binding mode to OneWay like

```
<TextBox Name="txt1" Text="{Binding taxpercent, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: Hi Soni, But after editing, no need to sort. Sort is allowed only after clicking the GridViewColumnHeader. No need to sort when editing the cell value. Here my issue is, automatically the column sorts soon after i edited or lost the focus from the cell. This is wrong. Any way to prevent this strange behaviour ???

Comment: I changed to Mode=OneWay, but still it is sorting soon after
losing focus from the text Box [cell template].
Sort should happen only clicking on GridViewColumnHeader only.
But why it is sorting if we click anywhere [in rows] in the listview.
This automatic sort is not using my "Sorting code".
This is happenening from the listview control itself.
Any Idea about ?

Comment: I want the sort to be done only by clicking the header. So used OneWay Mode and removed UpdateSourceTrigger. Still the same issue.

Comment: In the UserControl_Loaded event, i register the event,   this.AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler));

Comment: In the GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler,  ListSortDirection direction;
            GridViewColumnHeader headerClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader; then checking,  if (headerClicked != null && headerClicked.Role != GridViewColumnHeaderRole.Padding)

Comment: Which type of collection you are binding to your GridView? If it is List or ObservableCollection cant you just use OrderBy in HeaderClick event?

Comment: DataView is the ItemSource of my listview. We are getting DataTable from DB. There is no MVVM.

Comment: if we clear the sortdescription after the refresh, sort will not work. So that is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

change your sort code like this

```
ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvTax.ItemsSource);
    if (dataView != null)
    {     
    using (dataView.DeferRefresh())
    {        
        dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        SortDescription sd = new SortDescription("taxpercent", direction);
        dataView.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
    }            
    }
```

This may prevent your datagrid to automatically refresh every time

Thanks to Matthew Manela [Defer Automatic refresh](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matt/archive/2008/08/28/collectionview-deferrefresh-my-new-best-friend.aspx)

Comment: Hi, Still No Use At All !!. But sometimes if i type in new value and wait for 2 or 3 sec then click another row or column, it will not sort. [But sometimes sorts if i edited the first or last row cell value]. But soon after type in and click any other row or column, it sorts !! Why it is so ?